# Link a binary variable to continuous variable in Java Gurobi

Tags: optimization, gurobi, java

I have the following problem:

Depending on my continuous optimization variable $S_m$, I would like to introduce a binary variable $x_m$, which, depending on the value of $S_m$ (greater or less than 0) receives the value 0 or 1. The whole thing is to be repeated for 12 months. I have already created both variables, I just don't know how to link them, so that $x_m$ has no influence on $S_m$, and the value for $x_m$ depends purely on the value of $S_m$.

Comment: You may find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22849589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to model it as follows:

$$
S_m \leq a + bx_m \\
S_m \geq ax_m
$$

where $a$ is the switch and $a+b$ is the upper bound for variable $S_m$. In this case, if $S_m< a$, then $x_m$ has to be 0 (otherwise this is infeasible). Similarly, if $S_m > a$, then $x_m$ has to be 1. The key question here is what you want to happen if $S_m = a$, but that is something that depends on your business requirements.

To answer your questions, you can model these things using a simple linear constraint, see the Gurobi Java documentation [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/java_model_addconstr.html).

Comment: what exactly do you mean by a is the switch. Or I have just a thinking error. My lower limit is -100, the upper limit is 150, but as I said, the question is whether S_m is greater than or less than zero, and thus whether x_m is 1 or 0, which I need in other constraints.

Comment: Ahh, ok. In that case you would have $a=0$ and $b=150$:

$$
S_m \leq 150x_m \\
S_m \geq -100 + 100x_m
$$

You still have to decide what to do at $S_m=0$ though, because that behaviour will depend on the objective function.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Richard mentioned:

1. You can consider $a=0$ and $b=\epsilon$ in @Richard's answer.
2. [Here](https://www.gurobi.com/pdfs/user-events/2017-frankfurt/Modeling-2.pdf) you can find how special functions in the constraint can be modeled using Gurobi. Yours is defining an indicator variable for $S_m$ to find out whether the value of your variable is positive or negative.

**Edit:**
you can model it as follow:

$$S_m \leq 150x_m-\epsilon(1-x_m)$$
$$-100(1-x_m)+\epsilon x_m\leq S_m$$

A positive $S_m$ will force $x_m=1$ via the first constraint. A negative $S_m$ will make $x_m=0$ while the second constraint is active.

Comment: what do you mean by consider   = ? what does  stands for?

Comment: @Handballer73 it is a very small positive constant value.

Comment: thanks a lot, i will try tomorrow

Comment: thanks again! I understand the equations. Only how do I implement this exactly in Gurobi (Java). I add the code in a new answer..maybe someone can have a look.  Also, is there a java command for this very small constant or just enter a very small value?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int m = 0; m < (int)this.Anzahl_Monate; m++)
    {
        constra = new GRBLinExpr();
        constra.addTerm(150, x_m[m]);
        constra.addTerm(0.000001, x_m[m]);
        constra.addConstant(-0.000001);
        
        model.addConstr(constra, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, S_m[m], "a");
        
        constrb = new GRBLinExpr();
        constrb.addTerm(100, x_m[m]);
        constrb.addConstant(-100);
        constrb.addTerm(0.000001, x_m[m]);
    
        model.addConstr(constrb, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, S_m[m], "b" + m);
         
    }
```

Comment: I think it would be worth pointing out that that `0.000001` was chosen as the tolerance to break the equality at $S_m=0$.